# Как организовать ревалентный поиск по нескольким запросам?

Tags: php

Меня интересует больше алгоритм. Суть в чем есть класс (таблица в бд) поиск в которой следует организовать следующим образом. Возьмем к примеру книги 
Условно пользователь выбрал три темы фантастика, триллер, космос. ему по ревалентности должно выдать книги с тремя темами потом следующими в списке с двумя и потом с одной. Elesticsearch, shinx не предлагать не потому что они плохие а потому что надо создать расширение в том числе для продукции не использующую эти решения.

Comment: `order by count(distinct тема) desc`

Comment: А что такое ревалентность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый найденный признак (жанр книги в вашем случае) добавляет "вес" строке. Остаётся отсортировать по убыванию веса, например, так:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT '000' t, 0 A, 0 B, 0 C, 1 D UNION
    SELECT '001' t, 0 A, 0 B, 1 C, 1 D UNION
    SELECT '010' t, 0 A, 1 B, 0 C, 1 D UNION
    SELECT '011' t, 0 A, 1 B, 1 C, 0 D UNION
    SELECT '100' t, 1 A, 0 B, 0 C, 0 D UNION
    SELECT '101' t, 1 A, 0 B, 1 C, 0 D UNION
    SELECT '110' t, 1 A, 1 B, 0 C, 0 D UNION
    SELECT '111' t, 1 A, 1 B, 1 C, 0 D
) t
WHERE 1 IN(A, B, C)
ORDER BY A + B + C DESC
```

Тут для примера во вложенном запросе образуются тестовые "книги" с названием в поле `t` и жанрами `A, B, C, D`. Если жанр у книги есть, в поле жанра `1`, иначе `0`. Жанр `D` нас не интересует и добавлен, чтоб показать как он не влияет на выборку. В результате получаем:

```
t       A     B     C     D  
---- ----  ----  ----  ----
111     1     1     1     0
011     0     1     1     0
101     1     0     1     0
110     1     1     0     0
100     1     0     0     0
001     0     0     1     1
010     0     1     0     1
```

Сложнее всего собрать эти самые веса. **Если** вы дружите с **нормализацией**, то наверняка жанры лежат в таблице много-ко-многому. Придётся использовать левый джоин. **Если** нужна **скорость**, а нормальная форма не волнует, проводите денормализацию - добавляете в таблицу книг поля - по одному для каждого жанра, но придётся менять таблицу, если будут появляться новые жанры. А можно (особенно если жанров нельзя выбрать слишком много) написать огромную портянку из запросов на все комбинации жанров, склеить их в одну выдачу юнионами и получить примерно тоже самое (значения для genre_id уже реальные идешки жанров, а не флаги 0 или 1 как в примере выше):

```
SELECT *
FROM books
INNER JOIN book_rel_genres A USING(book_id)
INNER JOIN book_rel_genres B USING(book_id)
WHERE A.genre_id = 123 AND B.genre_id = 456
UNION ALL
-- + такой же запрос, но только для жанра A
UNION ALL
-- + такой же запрос, но только для жанра B
-- и т.д.
```

А можно просто тупо собрать все жанры через запятую прямо в поле таблицы для каждой книги (не забыть добавить запятую слева и справа от значения), а потом суммировать число вхождений нужного жанра в это поле:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'foo' t, ',1,2,3,' genres UNION
    SELECT 'bar' t, ',2,5,9,' genres UNION
    SELECT 'baz' t, ',1,3,8,' genres
) t
WHERE (
    genres LIKE '%,1,%' OR
    genres LIKE '%,2,%' OR
    genres LIKE '%,3,%'
)
ORDER BY
    IF(genres LIKE '%,1,%', 1, 0) +
    IF(genres LIKE '%,2,%', 1, 0) +
    IF(genres LIKE '%,3,%', 1, 0)
DESC
```

Получим туже самую сортировку по весам:

```
t      genres
-----  -------
foo    ,1,2,3,
baz    ,1,3,8,
bar    ,2,5,9,
```

Но работать это будет не быстро. И чем больше книг в базе, тем медленнее. Вариантов масса. И я уверен, есть куда лучше!

Comment: у меня у меня через таблицу то еcть ganres, book,  ganres_to_book связи ещё не делал (использую framework который позволяет связать данные без связи в базе данных) видимо надо будет связывать.